# How to access the websocket URL from C# which is in remote ip?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, websocket

My Websocket URL is like this
"ws://someip:port/demo/"

i am trying to access the URL and it will return the Json. I am new to C#. I tried the below code

```
var client = new UdpClient();
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("ipvalue"),portvalue );
client.Connect(ep);
var receivedData = client.Receive(ref ep);
Console.Write("receive data from " + ep.ToString());
Console.Read()
```

but it shows invalid Url. I have tried other codes also, but its also error. Please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a Broadcast or Normal UDP connection.  Broadcast messages (like multicast 224-239 ip) you must listen at IP.Any not connect to server.

Comment: my ip does not in that range .. May be i'm completely wrong with the UDP approach. Can you guide me? But a listener running in that ip

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using UDP.  There may be an issue with port number being blocked or being used by different protocol.  Use cmd.exe >netstat/a to determine if port is open on server.  Use a port number > 1024.

Comment: i checked and its open... Now How can i receive the result from this URL "ws://someip:port/demo/"? may be a code snippet will help me..

Comment: You server service has to have a udp client running.  All he communications are performed through the clients (one on the local PC and one on the remote PC).

Comment: What has this to do with WebSockets? WebSocket is a protocol on top of TCP.

Answer (score 1):

#### WebSocket != Socket

WebSocket is a protocol built on the top of TCP and requires HTTP for establishing the connection. Unfortunately you're not going to achieve anything with `new UdpClient()`.

In order to connect to a websocket, you need to get a websocket library (alternatively, it looks like [.NET already supports it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket(v=vs.110).aspx)) and use it instead of creating a TCP socket.